# Same stylesheet for react js and react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Do we have a common stylesheet which we can use across react js and react-native?

If we define a styling then we must be able to use it across react js and react-native.

ex:

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    fontStyle: {
       fontSize: 20, //in web usually we give 20px and in react-native we give 20
       fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
});
```

fontSize is one thing which differs react js and react-native like that there are many things. Do we have any unified approach of styling which can be used across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Stylesheet.create](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/storybook/?selectedKind=APIs&selectedStory=StyleSheet&full=0&down=0&left=1&panelRight=0) from [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

The [quick start](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web#quick-start) has details on how to alias `react-native` to `react-native-web` in your babel config.
You can then use the same stylesheet file in both a react-native and a web project

Comment: react-native-web is using something like `fontSize: '2rem'` when I use that in react-native it gives error, that `Invalid prop 'fontSize' of type 'string' supplied to 'Text'`